# How to divide JFrame area into many areas without JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am working on a little Java Swing application by using `JFrame`. As per requirement I have to divide `JFrame` area into many sub areas.

I found in [Using two JPanels in one JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057836/using-two-jpanels-in-one-jframe) that I can do it by using a `JPanel` inside my `JFrame`, but I don't have to use `JPanel`.

Have you any idea how I can divide the `JFrame` area into many sub area without using `JPanel`?

Comment: The simplest way is to divide the UI into panels, which allows you to provide a different layout manager for each section, this makes it easy to generate complex UIs.  Otherwise, you need to use a complex layout manager, like `GridBagLayout` and even then, you're unlikely to achieve the results you want

Comment: What do you have against using `JPanel`s? If you tell us your goal, we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add something to a frame (`JFrame`), you actually add to his content pane, which is actually a container (`JPanel` is also a generic lightweight container).

The preferred way to "divide a `JFrame`" is to actually "divide" a `JPanel` and then set that panel as content pane of the frame. Something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

// ...
// layout panel, add components, etc...
// ...

frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

---

But if you really want to divide/split/layout a `JFrame` without creating a new container (a `JPanel` for example) this is the way:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is a fully working test class:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to learn more about JFrame check also this tutorial: [Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is seeming to work but i have a requirement that i have many check boxes and i want to set them vertical in BorderLayout.WEST area . is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Instead of BorderLayout you have to use another layout, maybe GridBagLayout. Check this to learn how to use layouts: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Yes , i have already used GridBagLayout , but i just wanted to know if any another way is available or not .. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: Another "way" (with your constraints to use the frame's content pane) means another "layout manager". Sometimes (and i think this is your case) default java layout managers are not enough or are too hard to implement what we want. We are lucky :) there are also other layout managers, lots of them open source. I recommend you [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).