# Add a shape into JPanel

Tags: java, swing

A quick and simple(?) question I can't seem to find an answer to.
Is it possible to draw a shape (rectangle, oval etc) and add to the JPanel, then add this JPanel to the JFrame? The examples of drawing with Graphics I found online added the shape directly to the JFrame. Example:

```
   public class DShape extends JPanel
   {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.drawRect(10,10,100,30);   
     }

      public class Test   {

       public static void main(String[] args)
     {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       DShape shape = new DShape();
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(shape);
       frame.add(panel);
       frame.setSize(200,200);
       frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

This code will simply display a blank JFrame. A green rectangle will be displayed if you add a DShape class object directly to the JFrame. Is it possible to add the shape to JPanel first, then add JPanel to JFrame? Thank you.

Comment: You're forgetting that a JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default, and you'll want to read up on Swing layout managers as that is the key to solving your problem. Now if you want to display one JPanel on top of another, that's a different issue and will require a different solution, including using just one single JPanel to do drawing and to hold child components rather than two JPanels.

Comment: This was original closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057836/using-two-jpanels-in-one-jframe. However, this is not an issue with adding multiple panels. I believe it  is an issue with painting, so I re-opened the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > The examples of drawing with Graphics I found online added the shape directly to the JFrame.

When you add the panel to the frame directly the default layout of the content pane is a BorderLayout, so the component gets resized to the size of the frame.

> Is it possible to draw a shape (rectangle, oval etc) and add to the JPanel, then add this JPanel to the JFrame?

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   DShape shape = new DShape();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.add(shape);
   frame.add(panel);
```

The default layout manager for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout`. A `FlowLayout` respects the preferred size of a component added to it. Your component doesn't have a preferred size so the size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `DShape` panel to return the appropriate size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working example.